# When <ResourceDictionary> has both direct resources and merged resources, why can't resources be found?

Tags: wpf

#### File app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="appBrush" Color="Red"/>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

#### File Dictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ct">
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource appBrush }"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then MainWindow uses the template defined.

```
<Control Template="{StaticResource ct}"/>
```

Run. It says cannot find appBrush. What's the problem?

Note, changing StaticResource to DynamicResource definitely lets it work. But what is the reason forcing me to make the change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your App.xaml to this and it will work:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
           <SolidColorBrush x:Key="appBrush" Color="Red"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary  Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I believe it is related to how resources are merged together.  In these type of situations, I always use a Brushes.xaml resource dictionary to define all my brushes, and merge that in ahead of any other resource dictionaries.

Comment: Works dramtically! Thank you. Yes, I would put all my brushes in one file but now I only have one brush.